# JQuery or Javascript to get label text in table cell with combination of radio button and label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with the first column having a combination of radio button and label. Please don't suggest to me to put the text in the radio button because I have a function that puts value on the label per row, so I can't merge it.

HTML:

```
<table id="template" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="rbDefaultPrice" class="radio" />
            <label style="font-size: 1em" class="price"></label>
        </td>
        <td class="startdate"></td>
        <td class="enddate"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$("#template").click(function (e) {
    //JQuery or JS to get label text value
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear to me?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish here ?

Comment: Need a JQuery or Javascript  that gets the text of the label inside a cell with a combination of radiobutton and label. Currently have a working answer in alert format, but still implementing it in my function that checks the clicked value and looping in each rows

Answer (score 0):

Select the label and then get the html.

```
$("#template").click(function (e) {
     //console.log or whatever you want to do with it
     console.log(  $('.price').html()  )
});
```

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain to me what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: This actually works! Don't know why I haven't thought of this! Thanks man!  Just need to implement this to put in textbox instead of console log or alert then I'll tag this as accepted answer. As for the down voter, please don't down vote answers for no reason